# Pure functional tree with parent pointer

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I know that RB tree with left and right child can be implemented in pure functional way without degrading log n performance. Can tree with parent pointer be implemented in logarithm time? Seems like cyclic reference child->parent and parent->child requires all tree to be cloned, thus linear time.

Comment: If your data structure includes a pointer in the low-level (e.g., Ansi C) sense, it is not functional any more. Maybe you are looking for a [tree with a zipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_%28data_structure%29)?

Comment: I know about double linked list with zipper. I'm not sure if I can insert say in the middle without clone of the zipper.

Comment: you can have a zipper over a structure which has other zippers in, but you can't use that to make a "pointer" to the structure itself, only to another data structure, which could be a previous "incarnation" of the structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fully persistent, purely functional data structures are tree shaped, but may utilize pointer sharing to become a directed acyclic graph. However, once you introduce a pointer cycle, you can't "change" part of that subgraph without copying that entire subgraph.

The solution is to add an indirection: You assign "identities" to values, which can be objects (like Clojure's atoms) or simple values used as look up keys (such as numbers or symbols). You can think of a immutable pointer as an implementation of IDeref which always returns the same object. A cyclic graph can be represented as an adjacency graph, where "deref-ing" a node by name is the same as looking it up in a the map of names to nodes.

For more information on representing fully persistent graphs, see [Fully Persistent Graphs - Which One to Choose?](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/abstracts.html#IFL97).